# Hi, How can I remove some symbols in string and make rest words listed?

Tags: python, string

I have a string variable like below.

```
AKT= PDK1 & ~ PTEN
AP1= JUN & (FOS | ATF2)
Apoptosis= ~ BCL2 & ~ ERK & FOXO3 & p53
ATF2= JNK | p38
ATM= DNA_damage
BCL2= CREB & AKT
```

I want to remove `'&'`, `'~'`, `'('`, `')'`, `'or'` and to list words left like below.

```
AKT = ['PDK1', 'PTEN']
AP1 = ['JUN', 'FOS', 'ATF2']
...
```

Comment: Assuming your inputs are only letters, look at the [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) in python. Consider stripping all but these (`string.translate`) and then splitting all on spaces.

Comment: Seems a bit congested but it can get you started `import re; ' '.join(re.split('&|~|\(|\)|or',AKT)).split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do this,

```
s = '''AKT= PDK1 & ~ PTEN
AP1= JUN & (FOS | ATF2)
Apoptosis= ~ BCL2 & ~ ERK & FOXO3 & p53
ATF2= JNK | p38
ATM= DNA_damage
BCL2= CREB & AKT'''


import re

final_list = []
for line in s.split('\n'):
    valid_words = re.findall(r'\w+', line)
    rhs = valid_words[0]
    lhs = valid_words[1:]
    final_list.append([rhs, lhs])

for item in final_list:
    print(item[0],'=', item[1])
```

Outputs:

```
AKT = ['PDK1', 'PTEN']
AP1 = ['JUN', 'FOS', 'ATF2']
Apoptosis = ['BCL2', 'ERK', 'FOXO3', 'p53']
ATF2 = ['JNK', 'p38']
ATM = ['DNA_damage']
BCL2 = ['CREB', 'AKT']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` and `join`, i.e.

```
APT = APT.split('&') #APT = ['PDK1', '~PTEN']
APT = join(APT)
APT = split('~')
APT = join(APT)
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you can't call `join` or `split` just like that without a `str` object to operate on.